Consider the following recurrence, $a_n = \frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}+1$ where $a_1 = 1$. Guess a pattern for $a_n$ and prove it by induction.
Consider the following recurrence,
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}+1$$
where $a_1 = 1$.
(a) Guess a pattern for $a_n$ and prove it by induction.
(b) Convert the recurrence for $a_n$ into the form $a_n = Aa_{n−1} + Ba_{n−2}$ by eliminating the constant $1$ in the recurrence. Solve for $a_n$ using the characteristic equation.
(c) Find $a_n$ using the generating function method.
What I did
I did find a pattern.
$$a_n=\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}, n>1$$
I am stuck on how to convert the function into the form $a_n = Aa_{n−1} + Ba_{n−2}$ by eliminating the constant $1$ in the recurrence. Also how to find $a_n$ using the generating function method.
NOTE: This question is more than just the recurrence. It is also asking for the induction proof, characteristic equation, and generating function method. It is entirely different from this question: Solve the recurrence relation $a_n={1\over2}a_{n-1}+1$, $a_1=1$. Please re-open.

Try recurring it out with some values.

According to your $a_n$, $a_2$=3/2 and $a_3$=9/4, but it's 7/4 actually

By subtracting the recurrence equations $(1)-(2)$ where $$\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac12 a_{n-1}+1 \tag1\
a_{n-1} &= \frac12 a_{n-2}+1 \tag2\
\end{align*}$$

@peterwhy OP wanted induction, characteristic equation and generating functions though.

In order for your question to be reopened, maybe you could edit your post to show your own attempts to answer your question(s!), and explain what stopped you.

What do you think about the 3 answers below using different methods, and the answers in the linked duplicate? If you need more details, maybe comment under them and ask for clarification?

$$a_n=\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n-1}},n>1$$
It successfully works for $n=2$.
I have to prove
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n}$$
$$RHS=\frac{2^n -1+2^n}{2^n}=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}+1=\frac{1}{2}×\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}+1=\frac{1}{2}a_n+1$$
$$LHS=a_{n+1}$$
We get the original recursion formula back.
Hence it's proved by induction.
For (b), as @peterwhy said in the reply,
$$a_n=\frac{3}{2}a_{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-2}$$
You can proceed yourself for the last part

You can prove it too by defining the generating function $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}a_nx^n$ as c) requests:
$$\begin{aligned}
S(x)\equiv\sum_{n\geq 1}a_nx^n&=x+\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 2}a_nx^n\\
&=x+\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 2}\left[\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}+1\right]x^n\\
&=x+\frac{x}{2}\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\sum_{n\geq 2}x^n\\
&=x+\frac{x}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}a_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n\geq 2}x^n\\
&=x+\frac{x}{2}S(x)+\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)S(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}&\implies S(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x)(2-x)}=\frac{2}{1-x}-\frac{2}{1-x/2}\\
&\implies S(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} 2x^n-\sum_{n\geq 0} 2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}x^n
\end{aligned}$$
Since the $n=0$ term in the last summation is $0$, we get
$$S(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_nx^n=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}x^n=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}x^n$$
and by comparison it can be seen
$$a_n=\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}},\ \text{ for }n\geq 1.$$

You can solve it just like you'd solve any differential equation (sic) :

solve the homogenous equation;
find a particular solution;
apply your initial condition.

The homogenous equation is $a_n=\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}$, so solutions to the homogenous equation are geometric sequence of ratio $\frac{1}{2}$;
The constant sequence $a_n = \lambda = 2$ is a particular solution.
Therefore there exists $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $a_n =\frac{C}{2^n}+2$.
Since $a_1=1$, $C=-2$ and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $a_n=\frac{-1}{2^{n-1}}+2=\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n-1}}$.
